# How can I get "new MVC item" options to appear in AddItem menu, when project is a Dynamic Data project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, dynamic-data

I've started with a VS2010 Dynamic Data project, but now I want to add other MVC type pages etc.

How can I get "new MVC item" options to appear in AddItem menu?

i.e. this seems to appear in an MVC created project, but if I started with a DD project how can I make the option appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC doesn't play well in Dynamic Data projects.

However, most of DD is in MVC 2. You should create an MVC project and use the "dynamic templated views" feature rather than try and make MVC and DD cooperate.

Comment: thanks Craig - can I ask what's the reason for this advice?  Like is it to avoid DD it's own specific Site.master & Site.css? (by the way - I've now managed to get a basic MVC2 web app and add DD to it by copying it from an test DD project - next step however is how to integrated the two in nicely with the web site layout navigation I want - so your advice is probably pertinent)

Comment: I tried it a while back and found "plain" DD to be not very tweak-able. It's designed to be an "instant site" rather than "close to the metal" like MVC. MVC 2 has enough to build DD, but you can't build MVC with DD.

Comment: can I confirm what you meant exactly by "dynamic templated views" of MVC - Like for example what link at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394709%28v=VS.100%29.aspx  would cover what you were suggestion (thanks)

Comment: Look here http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html and here http://haacked.com/archive/2009/08/04/default-templated-views.aspx